# Instantiate an array of buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, instantiation

I need to instantiate/create buttons inside a table. I would like the buttons to all be labelled and then also coloured, however from my research and testing I believe I can only have one or the other. I'd like them inside a scrollable table.

```
        public void OnGUI()
{
    //create a window
    GUI.Window(0, windowRect, WindowFunction, "Meeting Request Viewer");
}
public void WindowFunction(int windowID)
{
    //Fetches all user Data
    string[][] userArray = GetComponent<Userdata>().CallDetail();

    string[][] StudentArray = GetComponent<Userdata>().UserSorting(userArray);

    Debug.Log("here");
    //Calls the SortStudentArray method
    string[,] SortedStudentArray = SortStudentList();        

    //Creates a box with a scrolling bar to taverse the y axis
    scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(Screen.width / 6, Screen.height / 6, 350, 250), scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 300, 40 * SortedStudentArray.Length));

    //for each row in the sorted student array
    for (int x = 0; x < SortedStudentArray.Length; x++)
    {
        GameObject StudentButton = Instantiate(GUI.Button(new Rect(0, BSpace, 300, 20), (SortedStudentArray[x, 6])));

        //This keeps the gap between each button consistent
        BSpace = +scrollPosition.height;
    }    

    GUI.EndScrollView();

}
```

Comment: Just a little hint: use property-files or lot of constants to avoid magic-numbers. Later no one knows why `Screen.width/6` should be used or at other place you won´t know the width formula and variable would be great.

Comment: Mind showing us where this code is?  is it in `OnGUI()`? also what is `SortedStudentArray`?

Comment: Added code to the question, also this is the only location that I use `Screen.width/6` but i'll make sure I annotate why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to label and color buttons at the same time. Unity's **GUI** is an Immediate Mode system so you don't Instantiate and must set GUI.color* before each call to GUI.Button. Here's an example;

```
public int ButtonSpacing = 10;
public int ButtonWidth = 80;
public int ButtonHeight = 30;

public string[] Labels = { "Black", "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
public Color[] Colors = { Color.black, Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue };

private void OnGUI ()
{
    var y = ButtonSpacing + ButtonHeight;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        GUI.backgroundColor = Colors[i];
        GUI.Button(new Rect(ButtonSpacing, ButtonSpacing + i * y, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight), Labels[i]);
    }
}
```

*There are actually three ways to color the GUI. The options are `GUI.backgroundColor`, `GUI.contentColor` and `GUI.color`. Please see the [GUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.html) docs for more information on their usage.

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you! How do I register which button has been pressed?

Comment: GUI.Button will return a boolean indicating whether or not it's been clicked in that frame. True if it has, false otherwise. So you can just `if (GUI.Button()) DoSomething();`